# New Functionality for TopicControl listAllSubscriptions Methods of ActiveMQ Artemis

Tags: activemq-artemis

In ActiveMQ Artemis 1.5.6 all subscriptions of a topic can be fetched by invoking `listAllSubscriptions` of [`TopicControl`](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/javadocs/javadoc-1.5.6/org/apache/activemq/artemis/api/jms/management/TopicControl.html) through Jolokia, e.g.:

```
.../jolokia/exec/org.apache.activemq.artemis:type=Broker,brokerName="broker-name",module=JMS,serviceType=Topic,name="topic-name"/listAllSubscriptions()"
```

I'm trying to upgrade to Artemis 2.x, but the interface is not there anymore. How I can get all subscriptions for a topic through Jolokia right now?

Comment: it is also okay to upgrade it to 2.17.0, but the interface is still not there after 1.5.6. Let me update the version in the question as [2.0.0,) which makes it more meaningful, thank you for the feedback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every subscription on a JMS topic is represented in ActiveMQ Artemis as a queue on the corresponding address. Therefore, you can read the `QueueNames` attribute on the `AddressControl` that corresponds to the JMS topic. The Jolokia URL would be something like this:

```
...jolokia/read/org.apache.activemq.artemis:broker="broker-name",component=addresses,address="topic-name"/QueueNames
```

A non-durable subscription will be represented by a queue whose name is a random ID. A durable subscription will be represented by a queue whose name incorporates the client ID and subscription name provided via the JMS API when the subscription was created.

If you need additional details about the subscription (e.g. the number of messages it contains, what filter/selector it's using, etc.) then you can simply query the queue via Jolokia to get that information.

As you've noticed, the management API changed significantly between ActiveMQ Artemis 1.x and 2.x. This is because we wanted to consolidate management to the concepts and resources of the core broker rather than any of the particular APIs or protocols it supported. Therefore, all the JMS-specific management resources were removed. See [this commit](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/commit/0189f156ec951824e7a0f0ca93f1d7ae28db754c) for more details.

Keep in mind that moving from 1.x to 2.x is a "major" version upgrade which is not guaranteed to be backwards compatible.

Comment: perfect, thanks a lot @Justin. Yesterday I tried it and observe it was working. However, I can see such logs 
"AMQ153005: Unable to retrieve "test" from JNDI. Creating a new "javax.jms.Topic" named "jms.topic.test" to be used by the MDB." for the definitions  <jms-topic name="test" entries="test"/>. Hence I had to query the topic name as "jms.topic.test". Do you know why I am getting these warnings?

Comment: Please ask a new question about the JNDI issue. That's obviously related to the upgrade, but it's really a completely separate issue.